# wait_for_completion for submit_bio in make_request not returning

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, block-device

I am writing a custom block driver in the Linux kernel and in my make_request routine, on writes I need to read the data of the bio's specified sector (from the physical drive) prior to writing the new data. My excerpt below showcases most of what I am trying to accomplish but for whatever reason, I never get a return from the wait_for_completion. Once I/O is executed to the block device. It hangs after the submit_bio and never continues. Every 120 seconds I get a stack dump and message saying how the task is blocked. Any ideas? Thoughts?

```
... in make_request ....

if(rw != READ){
    struct completion event;
    struct bio *biow = bio_alloc(GFP_NOIO, bio_segments(bio));
    biow->bi_bdev = bio->bi_bdev;
    biow->bi_sector = bio->sector;
    biow->bi_rw = READ_SYNC;
    biow->bi_vcnt = bio_segments(bio);
    biow->bi_size = bio->bi_size;
    init_completion(&event);
    biow->bi_private = &event;
    biow->bi_end_io = bi_complete;
    submit_bio(READ_SYNC, biow);
    wait_for_completion(&event);
    .... some more magic occurs here ....
}
generic_make_request(bio);
```

---

Comment: Which part of the code is responsible for calling `complete()` or the like for that event? In what conditions was that part of the code meant to execute?

Comment: @Eugene, The bi_complete routine is set to the biow->bi_end_io. It is this that calls the complete().
    
    `static void bi_complete(struct bio *bio, int error)
    {
        complete((struct completion *)bio->bi_private);
    }`

Identical to the one found in the MD code of the kernel.

Comment: Oh, and conditions? Writes. In my make_request. I want to read the old data of the Hard Drive prior to writing the new data onto it. So it should execute on all write requests.

Comment: Was this problem solved? The question is interesting IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a kernel thread, and do reading/writing ops in the thread. Really, I don't know why it works, I refer to relevant examples and try to do it, and find that it works.

To explain more clearly, I write the example as below:

```
static void trigger_some_event()
{
     struct task_struct *task;
     task = kthread_create(<your_func>, <arg>, "<desc>");
     if(task){
         wake_up_process(task);
     }
}
```